# How to convert rows into columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image]

into below result

[image]

Could not think of a solution here

Answer (score 1):

If that `id` column was a metric (number) on which you can aggregate, then you could do something like this with the `PIVOT` statement:

```sql
WITH in_table AS (
  SELECT 1 AS sku_id, 0.5 AS id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS sku_id, 0.6 AS id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS sku_id, 0.7 AS id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS sku_id, 0.3 AS id
),
out_table AS (
  SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT sku_id, id FROM in_table)
  PIVOT(SUM(id) AS sum_id FOR sku_id IN (1, 2, 3))
)
-- to check the input data as a tabular output
-- SELECT *
-- FROM in_table;

-- to check the output data as a tabular output
SELECT *
FROM out_table;
```

input data:

[image: input data]

output data:

[image: output data]

Having that `id` field with categorical values, I am not sure you could achieve a similar outcome. If you try to put just `id` in that `PIVOT`, then you could see this error:

> PIVOT expression must be an aggregate function call at [34:9]

Maybe there are other ways to achieve exactly what you ask. However, I hope the sample SQL above helps in putting you towards the right direction.